# How to build a dynamic UI in Swift/Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, user-interface

I have to build an app where I need to display UI elements according to the info I get from a database.

I have a TabelView with a custom cell which has a label and I have some text there from the database. This works. 
Now In the database for each cell I store this text and I have a column for other UI elements. For example if this column has 1 then I have to display a Button under the Label, if this column stores 2 then I have to display a DataPicker under the Label. 3 - Switch, 4 - Slider, 5 etc.

**Is it a good solution to put all the UI elements in the prototype cell IN A STACK VIEW, set the height to dynamic and always display (hide = true/false) the proper UI element?**

But if I have 10-12 different UI elements it can become messy and too long. So what's the best solution for this?

Comment: Hi I too have the same requirement,What is the best solution u had implemented for this.

Answer (score 0):

make an empty view where you will place element depending on 1 or 2 or 3 etc. method will place specific button, picker or something there UI will be faster this way

Answer (score 0):

> **Is it a good solution to put all the UI elements in the prototype cell IN A STACK VIEW, set the height to dynamic and always display (hide = true/false) the proper UI element?**

No, this is not the best approach beacause you're going to render all views for each cell also if they're not used. You should add these subviews programmatically with constraints, it requires more work but it's better for performance if you have many views. If you are dequeuing cells, you'll have to write your code good to avoid bad cell recycling.

Remember [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/) is available only from iOS9

Comment: Thank you. " If you are dequeuing cells, you'll have to write your code good to avoid bad cell recycling." What do you mean by this? Write good code to avoid bad cell recycling?

Comment: When you have many rows and cells go out of screen, if you're dequeuing cells, you could have some mistakes. Suppose that fifth cell is generated from first cell recycled and first cell was showing a button that doesn't have to be shown in fifth cell. You'll have to remove button from cell probably otherwise it will remain visible

Answer (score -2):

You can design dynamic scrollable screen which will adjust its size and scroll according to content

For this you need to do following

1. Add UITableView as parent view
2. Add container view inside parent
3. Add what ever content you want to display inside container view
4. update container view frame with last view in design in viewDidLayoutSubviews method

For details implementation please check the following video

Swift/iOS - Dynamic Scrollable UI Screen Design

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vA2CVpwC8f0&t=21s